# How to remove the whitespaces between points in scatterplot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have used the scatterplot command to make a plot of nurse schedules, however whenever the points are close, there is this annoying whitespace, which I would like to get rid of. An example:

[image]

So whenever the points are close there appear this white gap...

To plot the red dots I have used this command:

```
sns.scatterplot(x='xaxis', y='nurses', data=df_plot, marker=',', color='r', s=400,ci=100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your markers are being drawn with white edges. You can remove these using `edgecolor='None'` as an option to `sns.scatterplot`.

```py
sns.scatterplot(x='xaxis', y='nurses', data=df_plot,
                marker=',', color='r', s=400, ci=100, edgecolor='None')
```

---

A small example to demonstrate this point:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.scatterplot(ax=ax1, data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip")
sns.scatterplot(ax=ax2, data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", edgecolor='None')
```

[image]